# Using HTTPS in android google analytics

Tags: android, https, google-analytics

Is there a way to make com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker communicate over HTTPS instead of HTTP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Google has finally fixed this. According to the changelog HTTPS is a new default protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are any special settings in the analytics package to do this but a simple a work around would be to have a small webview with javascript enabled load a page on your site (which is https and has the regular analytics code, and has a url that is appropriate for the activity you are tracking) and then remove the webview when the page loads. Analytics should track it properly.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     if(progress==100){
        // window loaded remove
   }
 });
webview.loadUrl("http://yourpage");
```

PS: I haven't tried this but it should work